# how to integrate react native app with apache kafka

Tags: reactjs, react-native, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a kafka cluster with topic set up at backend.I need to fetch the message in frontend and process the information.

I tried kafkajs and kafka-node ,both require additional dependencies which are not available with my react native app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The nodejs libraries you've mentioned are backend libraries.

You need to deploy something like Kafka REST Proxy, or your own server from which you'd use standard HTTP requests, rather than a Kafka client